# Java - Reading Comment from XML-File

Tags: java, xml, xml-comments

I have to extract comments from a XML-File. I couldn't find a way to get them using JDOM or something else. At the moment I use Regex and FileReader but I don't feel like this is the way to go.

Can you use something like JDOM to get comments from a XML-File? Or ist it limited to Elements/Nodes and Attributes?

Comment: If you want JDOM way to read comment you can refer http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch15s07.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a lexical handler. More information over here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html

Look at the `Lexical Controls` chapter.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Not the lexical control chapter but something about searching nodes, that fits my problem quite good.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest StAX, fastest and simple

```
    XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream("1.xml"));
    while (xr.hasNext()) {
        if (xr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT) {
            String comment = xr.getText();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using XPath? If yes, you can select comments with `comment()` function.